# How to get values from shared preferences for class by another class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to get a string from my shared preference file and use for more classes, but I don't know why not work.
My reader class is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class A {
    public static String url2;

    public void execute() {

        String URLPref = "URL";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.exam.search_preferences",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        url2 = prefs.getString(URLPref , "");

    }

    private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String string,
            int modePrivate) {

        return null;
    }


}
```

And the second class that uses the string

```
public class SearchHome extends Activity {

    static String url2;
    A cls2= new A();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);

        cls2.execute();
        url2 = A.url2;


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"URL:" + url2 ,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
...
```

Sorry for my bad english, I never learned.But I'm trying!

Comment: why are you returning null from getSharedPreferences method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `Context` to your class `A`, because you can get the `SharedPreferences` from a `Context` object. NOTE, an `Activity` is a `Context` to some extend

```
public class A {
    public static String url2;

    /** @param context used to get the SharedPreferences */
    public void execute(Context context) {

        String URLPref = "URL";
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.exam.search_preferences",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        url2 = prefs.getString(URLPref , "");
    }
}
```

And then pass the Context to your execute method

```
public class SearchHome extends Activity {

    static String url2;
    A cls2= new A();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);

        // pass context 'this' to the execute function
        // This works, because SearchHome extends Activity 
        cls2.execute(this);
        url2 = A.url2;
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

if your data is not confidential it would be a lot easier if you can make a class specially for shared preference and have other activities access it. you will save a lot of time and code will be a lot simpler to follow up

```
public class HelperShared {
public static final String score = "Score";

public static final String tag_User_Machine = "tag_User_Machine",
    tag_Machine_Machine = "tag_Machine_Machine",
    tag_Draw_Machine = "tag_Draw_Machine",
    tag_Total_Machine = "tag_Total_Machine";


public static SharedPreferences preferences;

public static Editor editor;


public HelperShared(Context context) {
this.preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(score,
        Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
this.editor = preferences.edit();

}


/*

* Getter and Setter methods for Machine

*/

public void setUserMachine(int UserMachine) {
editor.putInt(tag_User_Machine, UserMachine);
editor.commit();

}


public void setMachineMachine(int MachineMachine) {

   editor.putInt(tag_Machine_Machine, MachineMachine);
editor.commit();

}


public void setDrawMachine(int DrawMachine) {
editor.putInt(tag_Draw_Machine, DrawMachine);
editor.commit();

}


public void setTotalMachine(int TotalMachine) {
editor.putInt(tag_Total_Machine, TotalMachine);
editor.commit();

}


public int getUserMachine() {
return preferences.getInt(tag_User_Machine, 0);

}


public int getMachineMachine() {
return preferences.getInt(tag_Machine_Machine, 0);

}


public int getDrawMachine() {
return preferences.getInt(tag_Draw_Machine, 0);

}


public int getTotalMachine() {
return preferences.getInt(tag_Total_Machine, 0);


 }

}
```

Comment: i have included a snippet of code that would give you a rough idea what you should be doing

Answer (score 0):

```
 private SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String string,
            int modePrivate) {

        return null;
    }
```

problem is here.

```
 return null;
```

you have to return valid SharedPreferences object. otherwise you will always get NullPointerException.

Comment: What should I return then for example?

Answer (score 0):

Call this when you want to put a pref:

```
putPref("myKey", "myValue", getApplicationContext());
```

Call this when you want to get a pref:

```
getPref("myKey", getApplicationContext());
```

You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).

```
Different Modes:
1   MODE_APPEND
This will append the new preferences with the already exisiting preferences
2   MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING
Database open flag. When it is set , it would enable write ahead logging by default
3   MODE_MULTI_PROCESS
This method will check for modification of preferences even if the sharedpreference instance has already been loaded
4   MODE_PRIVATE
By setting this mode , the file can only be accessed using calling application
5   MODE_WORLD_READABLE
This mode allow other application to read the preferences
6   MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
This mode allow other application to write the preferences
```

[Read More](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make shared `prefrences object` in class where you want to have data

```
SharedPreferences prefrences = getSharedPreferences("my prefs",MODE_PRIVATE)

Editor editor = prefrences.edit();

String s = edit.getString("your key",value);
```

hope it helps !

Comment: That way I tried first, but I have 9 class which using same variable, and have 5 different variable. E.g. Url, search-filter, location-code.